# HTML CSS using fixed elements and resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I am a html/css/javascript beginner.

I am working on the project. Using nodeJS + websockets. I am haveing a problem with the styling.

I have Three fixed elements. I need them to resize properly on resize in browser window.

I am working on the styling in [scratchpad.io](http://scratchpad.io).

This is the code 
I have only included the styling part.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Corben:bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=shadow-multiple" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/subtle_white_feathers.png);
  border: 2px dotted black;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Nobil', Georgia, Times, serif;
  color:black;
}
#main {
  margin:10% 10% 10% 30%;
  padding:7% 2% 2% 2%;
  background: rgba(160,160,160,0.2);
  border-radius:12.5px;
  border:1px dotted rgb(200,200,200); 
}

#header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0 20 0 20;
  padding:0 100 15 5;
  width:100%;
  height:2.5%;
  font-family:'A', Georgia, Times, serif;
}

#title  {
  font-family: 'Nobil', Georgia, Times, serif;
  margin-top:0;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-top:20;
  font-size:300%;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/subtle_white_feathers.png);
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 1px #ccc;
  font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
}

#sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top:15%;
  left:0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.5em #ccc;
  margin:20 50;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/subtle_white_feathers.png);  
  border-radius:12.5px;
  width:
  }
#sidebar div {
  padding:10 15 20 15;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  border-radius:12.5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 100px 20px rgba(117,104,104,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 100px 20px rgba(117,104,104,0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 100px 20px rgba(117,104,104,0.5);
}
#upbutton {
  position:fixed;
  top:91%;
  left:94%;
  padding:10 15 20 15;
  width:7;
  height:14px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0.5em #ccc;
  border-radius:12.5px;
  background-color:grey;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#upbutton img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#upimage {
  width:5px;
  height:5px;
}
 th {
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(160,160,160,0.5);
    font-size:175%;
}

#sidebar td {
  text-align:left;

}

#sidebar thead {
  border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000;
}

#sidebar tfoot {
  font-size:75%;
}

#messages {
  margin-top:-50px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid rgba(160,160,160,0.5);
}

#messages td {
  padding:10 5 5 30;
  border-bottom:1px dotted rgba(160,160,160,0.5);
}

thead {
  text-shadow: 7px 7px 1px #ccc;
}

.name {
  width:1%;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-right: 1px dotted rgba(160,160,160,0.5);
}
</style>
<div>  
<a name="top"></a>
HIIIIIIIII
</div>
<div id="header" >
<h1 id="title" >
Enter Your Message Below
<hr>
</h1>  
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
<div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Users</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>__________________</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Keshav</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rachna</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
</div>
<a href="#top"><div id="upbutton"><img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/26045.png"></div></a>
<div id="main" >
<table id="messages">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2' >Messages</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td  colspan='2' >
        <hr>
          <form action="send();">
            <input type="text" name="message" value="Enter a Message">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Abc</td>
      <td>Hi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Keshav</td>
      <td>Holla</td>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Rachna</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't evaluated your code, but I did find an anchor tag without a closing tag and closing table row tag without an opening tag. What is that 'S' at the end of the code for?

Comment: As mentioned below in the answers, the media queries can be used to trigger different css for the particular client size. Your css has to accommodate the queries. Setting those elements to position fixed will make it hard to adapt to different size layouts. Try using relative position and floats & alignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a responsive web design it's best to use @media. It applies attributes only when the @media (viewport) is at a certain size when using min-width or max-width

Look up the dimensions of a specific device if you are aiming for one but the below mentioned are common devices.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) Portrait devices and smaller devices
@media (min-width: 992px) Notebooks and landscape tablets / smartphones
@media (min-width: 1200px) Large displays
```

So for a working example your element can go from rectangular horizontal to square to rectangular vertical like so:     http://jsfiddle.net/czf792r1/2/

NB: Resize the result browser horizontally to watch it change

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the example only resizes at specific values. Is there any way to have a gradual change?

Comment: A gradual change? If you want more things to happen at a slower pace you can add in more `@media` queries and make changed at each resolution. The sky is the limit. Let me know what you meant by gradual btw and I will try help out.

Comment: How would you like it resized? Could you give an example even if its a screen shot with some indications draw on it. I just loaded your code into a browser to get a visual and I noticed you need to either add `margin-top: 80px;` or change your #header to stop is from being hidden by your header.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wyxf6ab5/1/ Use this here. Btw I dont think you need a media query to change on every pixel. But with a better understanding I can give a better answer

Comment: not exactly each pixel. I need something more gradual.With resizing of the different divs.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in your css - these allow you to have different styles for when the browser/device is differently sized.